# Unity c# Destroy does not set target to null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, null, gameobject

The problem that I am having is that target is not set to null when it gets destroyed. Instead, unity says *missing(Game Object)* (see this [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5rj2.png)).

In my Enemy Class I have a property `health`. If `health <= 0` it calls `Destroy(gameObject)`.

```
 public void LocateTarget()
 {
     if (Target == null)
     {
         // target has been destroyed or out of range
         CancelInvoke("CreateBullet");
         Debug.Log("Hold fire");
         // locate a new target
         Target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy");
     }

     if (Target != null)
     {
         // Shoot at target
         ShootAtTarget();
     }
 }

 public void ShootAtTarget()
 {
     if (IsInvoking("CreateBullet") == false)
     {
         InvokeRepeating("CreateBullet", 0f, 1f);
         Debug.Log("Starting to fire");
     }
 }
```

Comment: You didn't even bother to show where you are calling the Destroy function and what object you are calling that on. How can someone help you without that?

Comment: Destroy is a unity function. It removes a gameObject from the scene. As stated in my original post I call Destroy when a turret is at 0 health or below 0 health.

Comment: I know what it is. You have to show where you are calling it and what object/variable you are calling it on.

Comment: I just noticed that I said Turret instead of Enemy. it is the enemy that needs to be destoyed not the turret. https://imgur.com/gallery/hT6Rr

Comment: can you not set the Target to null after Destroy()-ing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(Target == null || Target.Equals(null)
{
     // target has been destroyed or out of range
     CancelInvoke("CreateBullet");
     Debug.Log("Hold fire");
     // locate a new target
     Target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly null your all references of object you are destroying. 
In your case you have to set your target veriable to null before destroying gameobject.

Answer (score 0):

I feel unbelieably stupid. I called my locatedtarget function in start and not in update. Thank you all for all the help.